# Calculating double integral bounded by domain in Wolfram Alpha Notebook

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, homework, wolfram-alpha-queries, free-form-input, wolfram-alpha-notebook-edition

> If I want to compute Double Integral on a given region(See attached Picture)

> > How can I input this on Wolfram Alpha Notebook

[image]

Comment: integrate[integrate[1/(x+y)^3,{x,1,3-y}],{y,1,2}]  Check that very carefully to make certain that I haven't made any mistake.

Comment: integrate[1/(x+y)^3,{y,1,2},{x,1,3-y}] is another way of doing the same thing, but the order in which you give the y and x values is very important.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: Please post your code,not the picture,thanks.

Comment: `Integrate[1/(x + y)^3, 
 Element[{x, y}, 
  ImplicitRegion[{x >= 1, y >= 1, x + y <= 3}, {x, y}]]]`

Comment: @cvgmt Well, OP doesn't even know what to input in tihs case, so…

Comment: @xzczd Really, it's not that hard to input the problem as described: "integrate 1/(x+y)^3 with respect to x,y over the region x >= 1, y >=1, x+y<=3" -- It doesn't work, btw, at least in *Mma*, but it's a reasonable start anyone could attempt.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions about Wolfram|Alpha that are not related to Mathematica are off-topic on this site.