# Plotting a complete graph with a given image as vertices

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks, image-processing, image

[image]I am trying to plot a complete graph using a png image for the vertices. I tried a "drag and drop" approach with `VertexShape`, but the software gets blocked whenever I use it. I tried then to import the image first with the command `Import`, but I do not how to use it later. Here is my current attempt:

```
g=CompleteGraph[8, VertexShape-> Import["~/google-chrome-yellow-png-image-69499.png"]]
```

How can I give in input the png image to the VertexShape command?

[image: This is the error I get using Import]

Comment: tried `img= Import["~/google-chrome-yellow-png-image-69499.png"]; CompleteGraph[8, VertexShape->img]`?

Comment: Yes @kglr, it does not work. Now I receive a message "No Wolfram Language translation found" even for just the Import command. I do not why.

Comment: Penelope, I assumed the url in your post `"~/google-chrome-yellow-png-image-69499.png"` is a working url. Apparently it isn't.  Try, for example, `img = Import[
   "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e6/Rosa_rubiginosa_1.jpg/440px-Rosa_rubiginosa_1.jpg"];CompleteGraph[8, VertexSize -> Large, VertexShape -> img]`
`

Comment: @kglr I added to the problem text  a screenshot regarding the error I get just using `Import`. Maybe it is because I am using the Notebook edition, still it seems weird in any case.

Comment: You appear to be attempting to use `Mathematica` syntax in `Wolfram|Alpha`. `Wolfram|Alpha` doesn't appear to have a translator to handle that. Questions solely about `Wolfram|Alpha` are not appropriate on this site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about using Wolfram|Alpha outside of Mathematica.

Comment: As Bob said, Wolfram|Alpha and Mathematica are different systems. It is not possible to use Mathematica commands with Wolfram|Alpha (this is what you seem to be attempting). Wolfram|Alpha questions are not accepted on this site (except for questions concerned with accessing W|A from Mathematica).

Comment: OK, @BobHanlon, I understand. Still, during the last 9 months I used the Notebook edition exactly as using Mathematica (except that variables must have only one character). **All** the questions I asked here were about using my notebook edition and I could use **all** the answers I received. Maybe here there is a difference that I never noticed previously. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Szabolcs I see. Still, during the last 9 months I used Notebook Edition exactly as using Mathematica (except for the fact each variable can have only one character). If you look at the answers I received here,  I can tell you that I was able to use **all** of them. The difference between the language I am using with Notebook Edition and the original one of Mathematica is very, very small (as I said until now I would mention just the length of each variable). Finally, I think that the question is useful anyway for the users of this community.

Comment: On the other hand, I have always verified that the Notebook edition is **very** similar to Mathematica because I could use all the suggestions received on this community but... the same suggestions and commands do **not** work at all using https://www.wolframalpha.com/. I honestly think that the difference you are talking about is between https://www.wolframalpha.com/ and Mathematica. Notebook Edition is different from Wolfram Alpha (even if it is called Wolfram | Alpha Notebook Edition).

Comment: @Szabolcs, I added to the screenshot of what I got now using the suggestion of kglr -  As you can see it works without any problem now.

Comment: This is very interesting @PenelopeBenenati - do you think you might add some extra detail as a comment or an answer on [this meta](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2598/should-wolfram-alpha-notebook-questions-be-considered-on-topic) post about the topic?

Comment: @CarlLange yes, I will. The answer is not obvious, otherwise there would not be any question. I think that people who used both the systems can say something more about it.

Comment: Consider @CarlLange for instance the first question linked inside the question you provided me: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/240780/calculating-double-integral-bounded-by-domain-in-wolfram-alpha-notebook I am able to solve it with Notebook Edition by using **exactly** the same syntax of Mathematica.

Comment: Related Meta Q&A: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2598/4999

Comment: @MichaelE2 thank you, it's exactly the same link posted here in the comment (above) by Carl Lange. I will contribute to that answer. The point is simple: Notebook Edition also accepts the syntax of Mathematica with **very** minor tiny changes. Hence, if a question is a "Wolfram Alpha Notebook question"and it is a question for Mathematica too, then it is on-topic, because indeed it is about the Mathematica language. If instead it is **not** about the Mathematica language (which, I repeat, almost always can be used by NE too), then it is off-topic. For instance, my question here is on-topic.

Comment: (I do not know why I got the first mistake using `Import` initially). @MichaelE2 questions are about a language (except the ones strictly related to software issues), and they are independent of the software the one uses. In principle, one could post an interesting question without having **any** Wolfram product, but this says nothing about the **question**. It is the question that can be on-topic or off-topic, not the software(s) used by who asks it, right?

Comment: I agree. But there’s nothing wrong with the code you posted which works in Mathematica, so as far as the language is concerned, there’s no question to be answered, right?  `Rasterize` is unnecessary, despite David’s advice.  One might point out that the rose is a rather large image and you might be running into limitations — but I don’t know how to verify that as it’s system dependent.

Comment: @MichaelE2 are you saying that the following code works in Mathematica? 
`g=CompleteGraph[8, VertexShape-> Import["~/google-chrome-yellow-png-image-69499.png"]]`

Comment: It works when I replace your image with one I have access to, that is, if `Import` returns an `Image`.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your answer @MichaelE2 . Hence, it means that this is one of the very few parts of Wolfram Language that is not accepted by Notebook Edition.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I found a way to obtain the same results with Notebook Edition. It is sufficient to run first `Import`, then assign to a variable, say`r`, the result of `Rusterize[%]` and finally I can use `CompleteGraph[8, VertexShape -> r, VertexSize -> .5] `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    myVertexShape = 
     Rasterize[
      Graphics3D[PolyhedronData["Dodecahedron", "GraphicsComplex"],
       Boxed -> False], ImageSize -> 100];

CompleteGraph[8, VertexShape -> myVertexShape, VertexSize -> .5]
```

[image]

Or...

```
flower = Import["https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e6/Rosa_rubiginosa_1.jpg"];

myVertexShape = Rasterize[flower];

CompleteGraph[8, VertexShape -> myVertexShape, VertexSize -> .5]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! What about using a given image file .png that I have locally on my computer, instead of the dodecahedrons you created?

Comment: Just upload your image file and `Rasterize` it.

Comment: Thank you! Looks great!